# Variable length argument conversion in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

Just found something rather not comprehensible while converting a List into a variable lengh argument. In the worksheet i get this:

```
case class Sequence[A](as: A*)
```

```
Sequence(List(1,2,3): _*) //res1: Sequence[Int] = Sequence(List(1, 2, 3))

Sequence(1,2,3) //res3: Sequence[Int] = Sequence(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3))
```

My understand is that (1) and (2) should be the same, and indeed the Type is both `Sequence[Int]`

What is weird is that one is a `WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)` and the other a `List(1, 2, 3)` inside the sequence.

I am not sure to understand that

Any explanation for the difference ?

Comment: `as: A*` is just sugar syntax for `as: Seq[A]`, but that also changes the way the method is called. So when you call it like `(List(1,2,3) : _*)` you are basically telling the compiler that you want to _cast_ that **List** into a **varargs** and since that is just a **Seq** and **List** is a _subtype_ of **Seq** then it just pass it. Whereas if you call it like `(1, 2, 3)` then the compiler under the hood needs to create a **Seq** for those values, so it rewrites it like `(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3))` - At the end, both are **Seqs** and you shouldn't need to worry about which concrete class is.

Comment: Nice !!! Thanks for the explanation.